# “Request missing required body param” error when creating entry on front end

Tags: craft3, error, frontend

I get an `Request missing required body param` error when trying to create a new entry on the front end. All required fields are being filled. Nothing changed except the craft version. Craft version is 3.2.0-RC2.

Has that something to do with the way drafts are handled in 3.2?

Edit:
Looks like Craft wants a entry id:

```
/…/controllers/EntriesController.php(848): craft\web\Request->getRequiredBodyParam('entryId')
```

Which, of course, is not available when creating a new entry. What is to be done?

Comment: I'm having the same issue since updating to 3.2.x. Is adding `<input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="">` the official solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added an empty entryId-field to the form which apparently solves my problem.

`<input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="">`

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, but this can't be a permanent fix, else I will have to review a ton of templates on a lot of sites...

Answer (score 4):

This was an unintentional breaking change. See https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4693

Update: Fixed in 3.2.9, which is now (2019-08-06) available https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG-v3.md#329---2019-08-06